# Using webmock to stub partial headers

Tags: ruby, rspec, webmock

I am creating tests using webmock. I want to test that a particular header field is set, but I don't care about other header fields. When I use this:

```
stub_request(:get, "https://myhost.com/api").
  with(:headers => {:user_agent => 'Custom user agent'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => '')
```

I get an error because I am not stubbing all the headers:

```
Unregistered request: GET https://myhost.com/api with headers {'Accept'=>'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Custom user agent'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "https://myhost.com/api").
  with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Custom user agent'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

I don't care about the Accept and Accept-Encoding headers - how do I stub so they are ignored?

Answer (score 3):

Web mock does partial matching by default. In your case, the `:user_agent` key is a symbol which won't match the string `'User-Agent'`. Converting to a string should work:

```
'User-Agent'=>'Custom user agent'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash_including:

```
     stub_request(:get, "https://myhost.com/api").
       with(:headers => hash_including({:user_agent => 'Custom user agent'})).
       to_return(:status => 200, :body => '')
```

Comment: When I use hash_including I get this error: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/276. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me. Haven't had any errors like that, sorry.

Comment: No need to write `hash_including` for partially matching headers

Comment: I also get the error described in https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/276 and unfortunately
the default partial matching feature of Webmock doesn't match the use case of `hash_including` which can match on keys alone rather than key value pairs. I would like for this solution to work, but in my experience it doesn't.